# Case Insensitive Index mapping in EF Core

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, unique-constraint, ef-fluent-api

Is it possible to create a case insensitive unique index in Entity Framework core using Fluent API?

For example, a case insensitive unique index can be defined in Oracle using the following SQL:

```
create unique index test on "Person"(lower("Name"));
```

However, as far as I'm aware the only option in EF Core is a case sensitive unique constraint, such as:

```
builder.HasIndex(e => e.Name)
            .IsUnique();
```

I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
builder.HasIndex(e => e.Name.ToLower())
            .IsUnique();
```

Answer (score 0):

From EF Core 5.0, you can use [collations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/collations-and-case-sensitivity).

```
builder.Property(e => e.name).UseCollation("SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS");
builder.HasIndex(e => e.name).IsUnique();
```

For oracle, you might want to try a different [collation name](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/column-level-collation-and-case-insensitive-database-12cr2#column-level), like `BINARY_CI`.